# Trouble reading a String

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)  
int x = S.nextInt();  
double y = S.nextDouble();  
S.nextLine();  //Why 
String z = S.nextLine();
```

Why do I need to type `S.nextLine()` after reading int & double before I can read a String ?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) might help you.

Comment: If i remove it , the program will ignore reading the String @KarolDowbecki

Answer (score 3):

If you have the following information

```
Line 1: 1.0 2.0 4.0(you are currently here after reading the double 4.0) \n
Line 2: (you are here once you eat that '\n' character using readLine())
```

Once you store the last digit: 4, you are still on that same line (line 1). You need to eat up that new line character. `s.nextLine()` will read until the end of the line and return an empty result. Once that is done the scanner is positioned at the beginning of Line 2.